# Is it possible to use multiple aws ses account in django project?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I want use multiple aws ses account in one django project...

for some customers, the email must sent from one account and the remaining users must get emails from another account..

Comment: Read this blog : https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/can-i-use-multiple-aws-accounts-with-ses/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use boto3 and connect to AWS using different credentials.

Install the boto3 package.

```
pip install boto3
```

Then connect to your AWS account and send an email (or more).

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

SENDER = "Sender Name <sender@example.com>"
RECIPIENT = "recipient@example.com"
CONFIGURATION_SET = "ConfigSet"
SUBJECT = "Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)"
BODY_TEXT = ("Test")
BODY_HTML = """<html><head></head><body><h1>Test</h1></body></html>"""            
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

ACCESS_KEY = 'foo'
SECRET_KEY = 'foo'
SESSION_TOKEN = 'foo'

client = boto3.client(
    'ses',
    region_name="us-west-2",
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)

try:
    response = client.send_email(
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Message={
            'Body': {
                'Html': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_HTML,
                },
                'Text': {
                    'Charset': CHARSET,
                    'Data': BODY_TEXT,
                },
            },
            'Subject': {
                'Charset': CHARSET,
                'Data': SUBJECT,
            },
        },
        Source=SENDER,
        # If you are not using a configuration set, comment or delete the
        # following line
        ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET,
    )
# Display an error if something goes wrong. 
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Sources:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-using-sdk-python.html
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/quickstart.html#installation